# Deleting lines that doesn’t succeed directly a specific value from a.txt

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, indexing

I run the code bellow, in which I used a flag to identify all the {'/epg//activate'} and then print the ‘data_EPG[event] ‘ only if the  flag is True as follow:

```
data_EPG = {}
lines = data.split("\n")
flag = False
for line in filter(None, lines):
   col = line.split(";")
   event = col[9]
   if flag :
       if '//activate' in col[9] or col[9]=='/app//standby' :
           data_EPG[event] = {
    #'@mac':{
     # col[6],
   # },
    'Ev':{  
      col[9],
    }
}
   flag == False
   if col[9]== '/epg//activate':
       flag = True 

   if event in data_EPG.keys(): 
       print(data_EPG[event])
```

Data example:

```
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642;/homepage/ws/click;TV
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908621;/epg//activate;
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /epg/menu/click;Grid
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /app//keypress;home,1
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /vod//activate;
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /app//standby;
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642;/epg//activate;
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /app//standby;
```

Expected result:

```
{'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/vod//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/app//standby'}}
```

A Data Example 2 (after the '//activate' in col[9] or col[9]=='/app//standby' condition):

```
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /epg//activate;TV
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908621; /homepage//activate; TV
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /vod//activate;Grid
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /voyager//activate;home,1
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /homepage//activate;
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /epg//activate; TV
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /live//activate;TV
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /main_process//activate
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /app//standby; 1
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /main_process//activate; TV
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /app//standby; 1
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /homepage//activate; TV
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /live//activate;Grid
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /app//standby; 1
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /homepage//activate; TV
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /live//activate;Grid
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /6play//activate; TV
```

Expected result:

```
{'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}} 
{'Ev': {'/homepage//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}} 
{'Ev': {'/live//activate'}}
```

In other words I only keep the occurences of `'/epg//activate'`, the first occurence of `'/xxx//activate'` or the first occurence of `'/app//standby'` that comes after an occurence of `'/epg//activate'`.

If you have any idea how I can modify my code to get the result I should have, please help. Thank you!

Comment: Would be easier to help you with a example of data. From which data exactly should you get the result you show, and not the other one?

Comment: @ zezollo an example of data:

Comment: XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642;/homepage/ws/click;TV
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908621;/epg//activate;\N
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /epg/menu/click;Grid
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /app//keypress;home,1
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /vod//activate;\N
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /app//standby;\N
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642;/epg//activate;\N
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /app//standby;\N

Comment: The result I should have:

Comment: /epg//activate

/vod//activate

/epg//activate

/app//standby

Comment: If you have any idea please help!

Comment: What you want is still quite obscure and your explanations contradictory: you say you "should eliminate all the {'/xxx//activate'} such as: 'xxx'! = 'epg' " and then in the desired output examples you leave a "/live//activate" or "/vod//activate", so, should they be eliminated or not?

Comment: Another question: do you really want to display different dictionaries and lose the previous content each time new relevant strings are discovered?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @zezollo . Actually Iwant to eliminate all the {'/xxx//activate'} such as: 'xxx'! = 'epg' that does not succeed directly {'/epg//activate'} and keep the others that succeed directly that's why I leave  "/live//activate" and "/vod//activate" in the example.

Comment: For your second question please what do you mean by "lose the previous content each time new relevant strings are discovered" ? Thank you

Comment: Well in the loop you replace `data_EPG[event]` by a new value each time you find a new `event`. (So if the same `event` is found several times, only the last value will be stored)

Comment: "/vod//activate" does not follow immediatly a "/epg//activate" in your data... do you mean you keep the "/xxx//activate/" that comes after a "/epg//activate" has been found?

Comment: That's true I replace data_EPG[event] by a new value each time I find a new event and in my data it is impossible to find the same event several times, each line of the data is unique in the example of the data I gave you  the symbols of each line refer to different values

Comment: I keep each time just the first "/xxx//activate/" that comes after a "/epg//activate" has been found

Comment: Well I've got a working script that works with your comment example data, but I can't absolutely ensure this will cover all cases (maybe you did not anticipate some?). I can post it, but tell me if there's something to change. Also it would be better to edit your question in order to include the relevant example and make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified like this (using two flags for the two different cases: `app/standby` *must* follow `/epg//activate` immediatly while any other first occurence of `/***//activate` must *not* follow `/epg//activate` immediatly):

```
data = '''
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642;/homepage/ws/click;TV
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908621;/epg//activate;
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642;/epg/menu/click;Grid
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642;/app//keypress;home,1
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642;/vod//activate;
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642;/app//standby;
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642;/epg//activate;
XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642;/app//standby;
'''
# data = '''
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /epg//activate;TV
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908621; /homepage//activate; TV
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /vod//activate;Grid
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /voyager//activate;home,1
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /homepage//activate;
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /epg//activate; TV
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /live//activate;TV
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /main_process//activate
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /app//standby; 1
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /main_process//activate; TV
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /app//standby; 1
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /homepage//activate; TV
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /live//activate;Grid
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /app//standby; 1
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /homepage//activate; TV
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /live//activate;Grid
# XXX;ZZZZZ;YY;DD;IIII;SSSS_92;AAAA;TTTTT;1516979908642; /6play//activate; TV
# '''

data_EPG = {}
lines = data.split('\n')
flag = False
appstandby_flag = False
for line in filter(None, lines):
    col = line.split(';')
    event = col[9].strip()
    if event == '/epg//activate':
        data_EPG[event] = {'Ev': {event, }}
        flag = True
        appstandby_flag = True
    elif flag and '//activate' in event:
        data_EPG[event] = {'Ev': {event, }}
    elif appstandby_flag and event == '/app//standby':
        data_EPG[event] = {'Ev': {event, }}
    else:
        appstandby_flag = False
    if flag and event in data_EPG.keys():
        print(data_EPG[event])
    if flag and event != '/epg//activate' and '//activate' in event:
        flag = False
```

outputs (using the first data):

```
{'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/vod//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/app//standby'}}
```

(using the second data instead):

```
{'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/homepage//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/live//activate'}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @zezollo, your script work almost correctly for my data in fact for a succession of events:

Comment: {'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/homepage//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/vod//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/voyager//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/homepage//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/live//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/main_process//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/app//standby'}}
{'Ev': {'/main_process//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/app//standby'}}
{'Ev': {'/homepage//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/live//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/app//standby'}}

Comment: {'Ev': {'/homepage//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/live//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/6play//activate'}}

Comment: The script gives this result::{'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/homepage//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/homepage//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/live//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/homepage//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/live//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/homepage//activate'}}

Comment: {'Ev': {'/live//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/live//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/live//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/homepage//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/live//activate'}}

Comment: I must add that **app/standby** as **/***//activate** must not follow **/epg//activate**  immediatly, the thing is that I should keep only the first one that appears.

Comment: So the optimised result I need in this case is: {'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/homepage//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/epg//activate'}}
{'Ev': {'/live//activate'}}

Comment: Can't check it today; also this should have been already mentionned in the question, it was not possible to guess this case before answering.

Comment: I'm sorry not mentionning this case in the question. If you have any idea, please help!

Comment: Sorry I had no time. You should give your second example in the same form as the data example in your post.

Comment: Your comment: "app/standby as /***//activate must not follow /epg//activate immediatly" changes the way the data must be handled. It does match your first example anymore... or how?

Comment: Thank you for replying.In fact it does much the the first example: for app/standby just like /***//activate we keep only its  first occurence  that comes after an occurence of '/epg//activate'.

Comment: Please find above in the post the second example in the same form as the data example.

Comment: I should add that if the first occurence of an /***//activate comes after an occurence of /epg//activate and was followed by a  first occurence of app/standby, we don't keep this first accurence of the app/standby and vice versa.

Comment: In your first example, you expect to get 'app/standby' in the result (last line), but you say "app/standby as /***//activate must not follow /epg//activate immediatly", so it should not show up. I don't understand what you want: finally, does it matter if the first occurence of "app/standby" or "***//activate" comes immediatly after an "epg/activate", or not?

Comment: Yet I modified my answer to try to match this new requirement. I am not sure that I did understand it well, but the outputs are as expected with each set of data.

Comment: I'm really grateful @zezollo, this code works for me. Thank you so much! I wish I had this capacity to do so ;)

Comment: Good that it helps! I hope this will also work in any other case!